# How to use and test the Android 4.0 Calendar API in the emulator?

Tags: android, api, calendar, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

Do most use real phones to test Google Account specific Android features?  For example, I want to develop/test the Ice Cream Sandwich calendar api and in the emulator I can add a Google Gmail account to the operating system, but the calendars never seem to sync.

Here's a related post:

[How to read and edit Android calendar events using the new Android 4.0 Ice Cream Sandwich API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7859005/how-to-read-and-edit-android-calendar-events-using-the-new-android-4-0-ice-cream)

My question is how do you test it?  I'd like to upgrade my nexus s phones and the galaxy 10.1 tablet but I'd also like to make sure the upgrade will be safe.  It would be nice if the emulator could support limited sync'ing, etc.

Thanks.

Answer (score 10):

One work around is to add you Google account as an Exchange account -- see http://www.google.com/support/mobile/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=138636&topic=14299 for info.

Basically, enter your gmail address, but change the server it connects to to m.google.com and enable SSL.

Comment: Thanks that seems to work for the login part, but no calendar events are ever sync'ed and you don't seem to be able to create events.  Is that true for you also.  The only thing that seems to work properly is the exchange calendar.  Very strange! :)

Comment: The Exchange work around is fine to test the new Calendar APIs (Content Provider and Intents)! Enable "Accept all SSL certificates" when setting up the Exchange account.

Answer (score 2):

I was never able to get a Google account to work since Google blocks active sync on free accounts.

The solution for me was to signup for a free outlook.com account and use outlook.com's active sync settings as I did not have access to an Exchange account.

The steps I followed are from [my blog](http://samuelhaddad.com/2015/06/16/add-a-calendar-on-android-emulator/) and are as follows:

- Sign out for free account at outlook.com
- Select a Corporate Account
- Enter username such as email@outlook.com
- Select Manual Setup
- Select account type of “Exchange” (This will allow us to sync with active
  sync)
- Enter Server as s.outlook.com
- Security type as SSL/TLS
- Select next
- Confirm settings.

Comment: Use your flags next time to suggest that questions are duplicates instead of posting essentially the same answer on multiple questions.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up. I will do.