# AVD emulator has no option to Sync with Google Calendar

Tags: android, google-calendar-api, android-virtual-device, data-synchronization, google-account

My app has functionality to add events to the calendar but in order to achieve this Android's calendar app needs to have calendars. 
In order to add calendars you have to add a Google account. So I added a Google account in the emulator. It shows up as sync is off:

[image: sync is off]

, so when I click on it there are no items there under data synchronization.

[image: no items]

When I go into the calendar app - Settings and click on the email address shown it says the **account isn't being synced**.

[image: account not synched]

When I click on the accounts and sync button I am back to square one, in an endless loop.

Note using the email application in the emulator the sync is fine. 
[image: email is fine]

Is there some undocumented step I am missing, or have Google turned off this feature recently for Google Calendars. Or do you need a Google Plus account to use this feature as they bug you in the account creation screen to use Google plus.

I am using Android 4.03 with Google APIs. I have also tried this on 4.2, and I am having the same issues.

Here is a logcat from when opening the settings menu all the way to clicking on the account name 
http://pastebin.com/9Fk8NA0i

Comment: Did you look in the logcat?

Comment: here is a logcat when opening the settings menu to the account name  [link = pastebin](http://pastebin.com/9Fk8NA0i)

Comment: I ran into same problem.Have you found any solution?

Comment: no, except for using a physical hardware device

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use and test the Android 4.0 Calendar API in the emulator?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7959847/how-to-use-and-test-the-android-4-0-calendar-api-in-the-emulator)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know it is too late to answer to your question, but I have encountered the same problem as you just now. May be it will be useful for someone. After several hours of intensive googling I have found supposed root-cause of the problem: "Starting January 30, 2013, users, other than paid Google Apps users, won't be able to set up new devices using Google Sync".
Here is the [link](http://support.google.com/a/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=2716936).

Comment: That link is only about syncing using the Microsoft Exchange ActiveSync protocol. That's irrelevant to syncing a Google Calendar on Android.

Comment: It does appear to be relevant when the only way to sync is ad an account with Exchange Active sync settings.

Answer (score 4):

I know this is older, but I did find a solution. Sergery is correct that you cannot use Google Sync with a free google account, therefore you cannot use a free Google account to sync the calendar.

The solution for me was to signup for a free outlook.com account and use outlook.com's active sync settings.

The steps I followed are from [my blog](http://samuelhaddad.com/2015/06/16/add-a-calendar-on-android-emulator/) and are as follows:

- Sign out for free account at outlook.com
- Select a Corporate Account
- Enter username such as email@outlook.com
- Select Manual Setup
- Select account type of “Exchange” (This will allow us to sync with active
  sync)
- Enter Server as s.outlook.com
- Security type as SSL/TLS
- Select next
- Confirm settings.