# Calendar in Android 4 emuator

Tags: android, android-emulator, synchronization, google-calendar-api

For development I would like to use the calendar in an Android 4 emulator but the option "Calendars to display" is empty and I am not able to add an account with calendar.

I found several solutions but none of them worked:

### m.google.com

Like adding account with [m.google.com as server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7959847/how-to-use-and-test-the-android-4-0-calendar-api-in-the-emulator) but it keeps telling me "You don't have permission to sync this server. Contact your server's administrator for more information." because it is [disabled for new devices](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!category-topic/gmail/iphone-ipad-or-ipod/oGeHuvTPtRM).

### CalDAV

In the link above they are talking about using CalDAV but how without appstore? I installed the [caldav4j](https://code.google.com/p/caldav4j/) apk to use CalDAV but it does not run. logcat tells me `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android.provider.Calendar$Events`.

### Add Google Account

If I add an normal Google account I can only select mail for sync, calendar is missing.

### Android x86

Maybe I could avoid this problem by using [Android x86](http://www.android-x86.org/) like suggested here as [performance booster](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6058689/956397).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it working using [AndroVM](http://androvm.org/blog/).

1. Download [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads) and an [AndroVM image](http://androvm.org/blog/download/) with gapps. Like `androVM_vbox86p_4.1.1_r6.1-20130222-gapps-houdini-flash.ova`. `vbox86p` is for phone and `vbox86tp` for a table with phone functions.
2. Follow the [configuration tutorial](http://androvm.org/blog/blog/2012/11/14/androvm-configuration-tutorial/): Import Virtual Machine, activate network
3. Start the VM and enter your gmail account during setup.
4. For debugging with eclipse: run AndroVM Config app (on mobile desktop) to get the IP and on the host: `adb connect [IP]`

Hareware keys: ESC = back, F1 = menu, Pos1 = home/unlock, End = lock

Btw: AndroVM is a speed rocked compared to the normal emulator.