# Adding exceptions to recurring events in android < version 4.0

Tags: android, exception, calendar, recurring

> Microsoft Office Project 2007 introduces effective work weeks and
>   calendar exceptions, where all calendar data is associated with a set
>   of "valid from/to" dates.
>   --[Microsoft Office Dev Center](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ms485348%28v=office.12%29.aspx)

*Google* also uses this [feature](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/google-calendar-help-dataapi/IGvMeQhxmfI).

Does *Android* Calendar (pre-`ICS`) support these features too? I tried Googling, but only found incomplete posts, such as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13633577/android-8-sdk-14-recurring-event-exception.

I learned on a [separate post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10100563/adding-calendar-and-events-in-android-4-0) that the way to access the calendar was through a *content provider*, however I have found no working solution

(for example, I tried using `"content://com.android.calendar/exception"`, but it results in an exception saying that it is an unknown url).

Any help to steer me in the right direction would be extremely helpful, as I have been Googling to no avail, and this *try and try again* stuff is not working well.

Comment: I don't understand your question at all. Add exceptions where? Also, what recurring events? Why would you add an exception to the calendar?

Comment: I have the same problem with you, my post is here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16915993/make-exception-event-from-original-recurring-event

Answer (score 0):

No. Android Calendar exceptions are officially supported starting with ICS (API level 14):

[image: CONTENT_EXCEPTION_URI]

-- [Android Developer Guide](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/CalendarContract.Events.html#CONTENT_EXCEPTION_URI)

Some versions may allow you to use the `Uri` you discuss, since it is derived from the [source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.0.1_r1/android/provider/CalendarContract.java#CalendarContract.Events.0CONTENT_EXCEPTION_URI):

```
public static final String AUTHORITY = "com.android.calendar";
public static final Uri CONTENT_EXCEPTION_URI = Uri.parse("content://" + AUTHORITY + "/exception");

//hence, CONTENT_EXCEPTION_URI = Uri.parse("content://com.android.calendar/exception");
```

however since it is not officially supported, it should not be considered reliable.

Comment: Hi @Phil I got this error 'java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown URL content://com.android.calendar/exception', My full topic is here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16915993/make-exception-event-from-original-recurring-event

Answer (score 0):

To answer your first question, yes, older Android has ability to have exceptions to a repeating event.

Since that API was introduced in API 14, It's probably a lot different than the previous versions' code. [This link](http://jimblackler.net/blog/?p=151) has some hints on getting events from calendars on older versions.