# Make exception event from original recurring event?

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, android-calendar, caldav

I found that `Events.CONTENT_EXCEPTION_URI` ([here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/CalendarContract.Events.html#CONTENT_EXCEPTION_URI)) used for make recurring event.
It's hardly to find document or code example from internet. So I try many ways

## 1 Insert as SyncAdapter

```
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(Events.ORIGINAL_INSTANCE_TIME, CaldavGlobalVar.getCurrentTime_());
    values.put(Events.SELF_ATTENDEE_STATUS, status);
    if(!username.equals("")){
        values.put(Events.ORGANIZER, username);
    }
    if(event.getSummarry()!=null){
        values.put(Events.TITLE, event.getSummarry());
    }
    if(event.getDescription()!=null){
        values.put(Events.DESCRIPTION, event.getDescription());
    }
    if(event.getDateStart()!=null){
        values.put(Events.DTSTART, CaldavGlobalVar.convertTIMEtomilisecond(event.getDateStart(), event.getAllDay()));
    }
    

   Uri exceptionUri = Uri. withAppendedPath(Events.CONTENT_EXCEPTION_URI,  String.valueOf(event.getEventId()));
    Uri syncUri = CalendarProvider.asSyncAdapter(exceptionUri, username,context.getResources().getString(R.string.ACCOUNT_TYPE));

    Uri resultUri = context.getContentResolver().insert(syncUri, values);
```

**resultUri**  return null, I didnot see any exception or any relation things, So I dig Android source code (from [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Calendar/+/320c1b11a8238ef299a401655d1ae06ffad45a47/src/com/android/calendar/EventInfoFragment.java)) and find out the way they use `Events.CONTENT_EXCEPTION_URI` So I change

## 2 Insert by "ContentProviderOperation" like [this](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Calendar/+/320c1b11a8238ef299a401655d1ae06ffad45a47/src/com/android/calendar/EventInfoFragment.java), in line 1003

```
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(Events.ORIGINAL_INSTANCE_TIME, CaldavGlobalVar.getCurrentTime_());
    values.put(Events.SELF_ATTENDEE_STATUS, 1);
    values.put(Events.STATUS, Events.STATUS_CONFIRMED);

    ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation> ops = new ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation>();
    Uri exceptionUri = Uri.withAppendedPath(Events.CONTENT_EXCEPTION_URI,
            String.valueOf(eventId));
    ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(exceptionUri).withValues(values).build());

    mHandler.startBatch(mHandler.getNextToken(), null, CalendarContract.AUTHORITY, ops, 1000);
```

But it show log that It installed unsuccessfully, I am so worry about that, may be Google not support it fully, I also list all Content Provider in Android, I dont has any exception uri (`Events.CONTENT_EXCEPTION_URI`) --`content://com.android.calendar/exception`

Exception throwed

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown URL content://com.android.calendar/exception
```

Does anyone have experience ? Any help are appreciate :)

Kind regards

Comment: No one answer my question, so I try to work around by slipt by exception event and relate it by "SYNC_DATA" column...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A small part of my code:

```
ContentValues args = new ContentValues();
args.put(CalendarContract.Events.ORIGINAL_INSTANCE_TIME, originalinstancetime);
args.put(CalendarContract.Events.STATUS, status);
Uri.Builder eventUriBuilder = CalendarContract.Events.CONTENT_EXCEPTION_URI.buildUpon();
ContentUris.appendId(eventUriBuilder, originalEventID);
try {
    final Uri resultUri = context.getContentResolver().insert(eventUriBuilder.build(), args);
    int eventID = Integer.parseInt(resultUri.getLastPathSegment());
} catch (Exception e) {
}
```

Comment: With that code, how does the calendar knows which date was deleted from the recurrence?

Comment: @basvk Hi Basvk, could you please share some idea about inserting an  exception with event begin time and event end time for a day..

Comment: I will try to explain: By specifying  `CalendarContract.Events.ORIGINAL_INSTANCE_TIME` you tell the `Calendar Provider` for which specific instance you want to change status. The `CalendarContract.Events.CONTENT_EXCEPTION_URI` is a special `Uri` that have to be used for this purpose.