# How to get Google Calendar events in android using google calendar api?

Tags: android

I have to get events from Google calendar into my own Android apps. How can I do this?

here I am used gdata lib , but in the for iteration i getting some id instead of tile.

Thanks in advance.

```
            DocsService client = new DocsService("myappname");
        try {
            client.setUserCredentials("example@gamil.com",
                    "pwd");

            URL feedUri = new URL(
                    "https://docs.google.com/feeds/default/private/full/");
            DocumentListFeed feed = client.getFeed(feedUri,
                    DocumentListFeed.class);

            // TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);

            String text = "";
            for (DocumentListEntry entry : feed.getEntries()) {
                // text += entry.getTitle().getPlainText() + "\r\n";
                list.add(entry.getTitle().toString());

            }
            return list;
            // textView.setText(text);
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ServiceException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: Show what you've tried so far. People will help if you ask specific questions about issues, not hand you full solutions to large problems.

Comment: hi did u manage to get the calendar list using google calendar api in android? could u please share how it could be done ? thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use [Calender Provider](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/calendar-provider.html) for that

and for events look at the link below :

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/calendar-provider.html#events

Here are some blogs and explaination for the same

http://www.grokkingandroid.com/androids-calendarcontract-provider/

And in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7859005/how-to-read-and-edit-android-calendar-events-using-the-new-android-4-0-ice-cream) is shown how to read and edit events in calender provider.

Hope this helps...

Comment: This has required 4.0 higher but I need to work 2.3 higher versions.

Comment: Do you know how I can get it to work with `react-native`?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use Calendar Provider

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/calendar-provider.html