# CalendarContract.Events.CALENDAR_ID not storing the event in the specified Calendar_Id in Android, using Intent

Tags: android, android-intent, calendar, android-contentprovider, android-calendar

Hi I am using the following Code to add a Event to my Android Calendar using Intent.

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_INSERT); // Even Tried Intent.ACTION_EDIT
        intent.setType("vnd.android.cursor.item/event");
        intent.putExtra("beginTime", cal.getTimeInMillis());
        intent.putExtra("allDay", false);
        intent.putExtra("rrule", "FREQ=DAILY");
        intent.putExtra("endTime", cal.getTimeInMillis()+60*60*1000);
        intent.putExtra("title", mtodoText);
        intent.putExtra(CalendarContract.Events.CALENDAR_ID,3);
        startActivity(intent);
```

But the issue is that this event is not saved or Created to the Calendar_Id = 3, but inspite that it is created to the calendar_Id = 1.
I am using the following code to retrieve all of my Calendar Events, And if I check the log cat output it shows the event is created in Calendar_Id 1.

```
Uri EVENTS_URI = Uri.parse(getCalendarUriBase(true) + "events");
        String sSelection = "((" +  CalendarContract.Events.DELETED + " != 1))";

        /*String sSelection = "((" + CalendarContract.Events.CALENDAR_ID + " = 3 ) AND ("
                +  CalendarContract.Events.DELETED + " != 1))";*/

        cur = getActivity().getContentResolver().query(EVENTS_URI, null, sSelection, null, "_id");

        if(cur!=null){
            while (cur.moveToNext()) {
                String taskname=cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(CalendarContract.Events.TITLE));
                String taskdate=cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(CalendarContract.Events.DTSTART));
                String s_id=cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(CalendarContract.Events._ID));
                String taskstatusflag=cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(CalendarContract.Events.HAS_ALARM));

                Log.e("Title:", "taskname: " + taskname);
                Log.e("DTSTART","taskdate: " + taskdate);
                Log.e("_ID","s_Id: "+ s_id);
                Log.e("HAS ALARM", "taskstatusflag: " + taskstatusflag);
                Log.e("Calender ID:",cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(CalendarContract.Events.CALENDAR_ID))+"");
}
}
```

My Logcat Out is as Follows:-

```
05-31 17:17:54.039    6518-6518/com.myapp E/Title:﹕ taskname: test1
        05-31 17:17:54.039    6518-6518/com.myapp E/DTSTART﹕ taskdate: 1464608459000
        05-31 17:17:54.039    6518-6518/com.myapp E/_ID﹕ s_Id: 22162
        05-31 17:17:54.039    6518-6518/com.myapp E/HAS ALARM﹕ taskstatusflag: 0
        05-31 17:17:54.039    6518-6518/com.myapp E/Calender ID:﹕ 1
        05-31 17:17:54.039    6518-6518/com.myapp E/Title:﹕ taskname: test Cal 3
        05-31 17:17:54.039    6518-6518/com.myapp E/DTSTART﹕ taskdate: 1464684678000
        05-31 17:17:54.039    6518-6518/com.myapp E/_ID﹕ s_Id: 22163
        05-31 17:17:54.039    6518-6518/com.myapp E/HAS ALARM﹕ taskstatusflag: 0
        05-31 17:17:54.039    6518-6518/com.myapp E/Calender ID:﹕ 1
        05-31 17:17:54.039    6518-6518/com.myapp E/Title:﹕ taskname: test guest
        05-31 17:17:54.039    6518-6518/com.myapp E/DTSTART﹕ taskdate: 1464694253000
        05-31 17:17:54.039    6518-6518/com.myapp E/_ID﹕ s_Id: 22164
        05-31 17:17:54.039    6518-6518/com.myapp E/HAS ALARM﹕ taskstatusflag: 0
        05-31 17:17:54.039    6518-6518/com.myapp E/Calender ID:﹕ 1
        05-31 17:17:54.039    6518-6518/com.myapp E/Title:﹕ taskname: test Cal 3
        05-31 17:17:54.039    6518-6518/com.myapp E/DTSTART﹕ taskdate: 1464694676000
        05-31 17:17:54.039    6518-6518/com.myapp E/_ID﹕ s_Id: 22165
        05-31 17:17:54.039    6518-6518/com.myapp E/HAS ALARM﹕ taskstatusflag: 0
        05-31 17:17:54.039    6518-6518/com.myapp E/Calender ID:﹕ 1
        05-31 17:17:54.039    6518-6518/com.myapp E/Title:﹕ taskname: test Cal 33
        05-31 17:17:54.039    6518-6518/com.myapp E/DTSTART﹕ taskdate: 1464695268000
        05-31 17:17:54.039    6518-6518/com.myapp E/_ID﹕ s_Id: 22166
        05-31 17:17:54.039    6518-6518/com.myapp E/HAS ALARM﹕ taskstatusflag: 0
        05-31 17:17:54.039    6518-6518/com.myapp E/Calender ID:﹕ 1
```

What should I do to explicitly create the event in Calendar_Id = 3, Using the Intent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're trying to do is not possible. The user will always be able to change the calendar selection when you launch the `Intent` to create an event (just like he can change every other value of the event before storing it).

There is a workaround though. You can create a placeholder event and call an `Intent` to edit it. Many calendar apps don't allow to move existing events to another calendar, so this would do the trick (unless the user uses a 3rd party calendar app that supports moving the event to another calendar).

I've outlined this workaround in [Specify calendar in Android event creation intent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36078949/specify-calendar-in-android-event-creation-intent/36160480#36160480). Btw, this question is the first result when I google the title of your question, which might explain the downvote.