# How to get device Calendar (default calendar) events and display in our Application?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, java.util.calendar

I am bit new to calendar. Can anybody suggest me how to get events (eg. birthday/meetings reminder) from default calendar (not google calendar or any other only default calendar) and display it in `listview`/`recyclerview` in our application?

Answer (score 0):

This [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7859005/how-to-read-and-edit-android-calendar-events-using-the-new-android-4-0-ice-cream) describes reading and writing to the calendar.  The key information you need to read the calendar(s) is:

```
Uri uri = CalendarContract.Calendars.CONTENT_URI;
String[] projection = new String[] {
   CalendarContract.Calendars._ID,
   CalendarContract.Calendars.ACCOUNT_NAME,
   CalendarContract.Calendars.CALENDAR_DISPLAY_NAME,
   CalendarContract.Calendars.NAME,
   CalendarContract.Calendars.CALENDAR_COLOR
};

Cursor calendarCursor = managedQuery(uri, projection, null, null, null);
```

Then you need to extract the data from the cursor:

```
ArrayList<String> ids = new ArrayList<String>();
try {
        if (cursor.getCount() > 0) {
            while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
                String id= cursor.getString(0);
                calendars.add(id);  
            }
        }
    } catch (AssertionError ex) { /*TODO: log exception and bail*/ }
```

Then you have the ids and need to query each one for events.  This is described in the accepted answer to this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5883938/getting-events-from-calendar).  Also this [github](https://github.com/david-laundav/CalendarService) repository has a solution.  Most of these approaches only work on versions of Android greater than 4.2.